# Grouping Sets in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    T0.Descr [Dimensions], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) [Total Occupies], 
    CAST(T0.MinLevel AS INT) [Available Size], 
    FORMAT(COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode)/ T0.MinLevel, '#.#%') [Utilized Percentage]  
FROM 
    [OBIN] T0 
LEFT JOIN 
    [OIBQ] T1 ON T0.WhsCode = T1.WhsCode 
              AND T0.AbsEntry = T1.BinAbs 
WHERE 
    t1.OnHandQty > 0 
    AND T0.Descr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING  SETS ((),(T0.Descr, T0.MinLevel))
```

The result looks like this

```
Dimensions                                         Total Occupies Available Size Utilized Percentage
-------------------------------------------------- -------------- -------------- ----------------------------
268 x 90 x 122                                     2              5              40%
190 x 333                                          2              6              33.3%
190 x 333 x 290                                    6              6              100%
268 x 90 x 170                                     1              6              16.7%
268 x 90 x 186                                     6              6              100%
268 x 90 x 156                                     9              24             37.5%
268 x 90 x 211                                     7              32             21.9%
268 x 90 x 214                                     10             32             31.3%
268 x 90 x 193                                     17             62             27.4%
268 x 90 x 258                                     39             106            36.8%
268 x 90                                           61             170            35.9%
61 x 122 x 65                                      122            170            71.8%
268 x 90 x 152                                     161            439            36.7%
NULL                                               443            NULL           NULL
```

But I need also need the total for other two columns:

```
Dimensions                                         Total Occupies Available Size Utilized Percentage
-------------------------------------------------- -------------- -------------- ----------------------------
268 x 90 x 122                                     2              5              40%
190 x 333                                          2              6              33.3%
190 x 333 x 290                                    6              6              100%
268 x 90 x 170                                     1              6              16.7%
268 x 90 x 186                                     6              6              100%
268 x 90 x 156                                     9              24             37.5%
268 x 90 x 211                                     7              32             21.9%
268 x 90 x 214                                     10             32             31.3%
268 x 90 x 193                                     17             62             27.4%
268 x 90 x 258                                     39             106            36.8%
268 x 90                                           61             170            35.9%
61 x 122 x 65                                      122            170            71.8%
268 x 90 x 152                                     161            439            36.7%
NULL                                               443            (Need Total)           (Total Percentage)
```

How do I achieve this using grouping sets or rollup?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK, Please check now is that fine

Comment: Good... although you could remove the excess whitespace and make it easier to read without having to scroll right.

Comment: Oh you haven't provided sample starting data... actual and desired results are good, but we need to see the data that produces them

Answer (score 1):

You can just sum those columns.

```sql
SELECT 
    T0.Descr [Dimensions], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) [Total Occupies], 
    SUM(CAST(T0.MinLevel AS INT)) [Available Size], 
    FORMAT(COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) * 1.0 / SUM(T0.MinLevel), '#.#%') [Utilized Percentage]  
FROM [OBIN] T0 
LEFT JOIN [OIBQ] T1
   ON T0.WhsCode = T1.WhsCode 
  AND T0.AbsEntry = T1.BinAbs 
WHERE t1.OnHandQty > 0 
  AND T0.Descr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GROUPING  SETS (
  (),
  (T0.Descr, T0.MinLevel)
);
```

The problem with though, is that it appears to be that the `LEFT JOIN` is doubling up rows. Instead use a semi-join, either `EXISTS` or `IN`, and now you can instead use `COUNT(*)`

```sql
SELECT
  n.Descr Dimensions,
  COUNT(*) [Total Occupies],
  SUM(CAST(n.MinLevel as INT)) [Available Size],
  FORMAT(COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(n.MinLevel), '#.#%') [Utilized Percentage]
FROM OBIN n
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM OIBQ q
    WHERE q.WhsCode = n.WhsCode
      AND q.BinAbs = n.AbsEntry
      AND q.OnHandQty > 0
) AND n.Descr is not null
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
  (),
  (n.Descr, n.MinLevel)
);
```

Comment: I cannot use SUM(CAST(T0.MinLevel AS INT)) [Available Size] and SUM(T0.MinLevel) the results are wrong

Comment: Without seeing your input data and expected results it's hard to advise. I do point out that your aggregation seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Using GROUPING SETS:**

```
SELECT 
    T0.Descr [Dimensions], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) [Total Occupies], 
    CAST(T0.MinLevel AS INT) [Available Size], 
    FORMAT(COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) / T0.MinLevel, '#.#%') [Utilized Percentage]  
FROM 
    [OBIN] T0 
LEFT JOIN 
    [OIBQ] T1 ON T0.WhsCode = T1.WhsCode 
              AND T0.AbsEntry = T1.BinAbs 
WHERE 
    t1.OnHandQty > 0 
    AND T0.Descr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS ((), (T0.Descr, T0.MinLevel), (T0.Descr), ())
HAVING 
    GROUPING(T0.Descr) = 0
    OR GROUPING(T0.MinLevel) = 1;
```

**Using ROLLUP:**

```
SELECT 
    T0.Descr [Dimensions], 
    COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) [Total Occupies], 
    CAST(T0.MinLevel AS INT) [Available Size], 
    FORMAT(COUNT(DISTINCT T0.BinCode) / T0.MinLevel, '#.#%') [Utilized Percentage]  
FROM 
    [OBIN] T0 
LEFT JOIN 
    [OIBQ] T1 ON T0.WhsCode = T1.WhsCode 
              AND T0.AbsEntry = T1.BinAbs 
WHERE 
    t1.OnHandQty > 0 
    AND T0.Descr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP (T0.Descr, T0.MinLevel);
```

Both of these queries will generate subtotals and a grand total for the "Total Occupies" and "Utilized Percentage" columns, as you've described. The HAVING clause is used to filter out rows that are not needed in the final output. The GROUPING function is used to determine whether a particular row is a subtotal or a grand total, and based on that, the appropriate rows are included in the result.